# DataTables Warning: Cannot view Activities after upgrade to 4.7.28

Tags: wordpress, activities, upgrade

I cannot view Activities on a Contact's Activities Tab, or my activities on my CiviCRM Dashboard. In both cases I receive the following error:

*DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1*

I am using CiviCRM 4.7.28 in Wordpress 4.9.1. I have the following Extensions active in CiviCRM:

- iATS Payments 1.6.1
- Summary Fields v. 3.1.1
- Extended Report v. 3.0
- Displays relationships in the contact summary v. 1.2
- Mailchimp v. 2.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix this regression, you need to apply this [tiny patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/6454ff5467e8c31bd32747a72169f15d640f1319), which wasn't merged in time for the 4.7.28 release.

Cheers,
Olivier;