# Activities not displaying and weird json message

Tags: activities, json

civi 5.9.13 WP 5.2.2
civi In a contract screen activities tab no activities are listed
error popup says "DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1"
EEK!
I've recently deleted various mysql data related to civivolunteer - hope this didnt break anything

PS I tried the fix here: [DataTables Warning: Cannot view Activities after upgrade to 4.7.28](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21796/datatables-warning-cannot-view-activities-after-upgrade-to-4-7-28)
didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.
On checking logs it was in fact missing civivolunteer custom fields.
restored them from backup and all good now.

Is this bad behaviour for an extension?

Comment: How did you delete the data?  Your reference to deleting 'mysql data' suggests you might have done this with direct sql - in which case the extension doesn't get chance to clean up any dependencies resulting in an inconsistent state.  On the other hand if you deleted via GUI and/or API then it should cope but if not, log an issue.